# Difference between C++ string declared as a variable and read in sctruct

Tags: c++, string, struct, types, printf

Recently, while being reintroduced to C++, I came across an exercise for which I wrote this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    string address;
    string telephoneNumber;
    float grade1;
    float grade2;
};

string situation;

int main () {
    Student student;
    situation = "failed";
    float media;

    scanf("%s", &student.name);
    scanf("%s", &student.address);
    scanf("%s", &student.telephoneNumber);
    scanf("%f", &student.grade1);
    scanf("%f", &student.grade2);

    average = (student.grade1 + student.grade2) / 2;
    if (average >= 7.0) {
        situation = "pass";
    }
    printf("The average of the student %s is %4.1f\n", &student.name, average);
    printf("And his/her situation is %s\n", situation.c_str());

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Would anyone know why to print out the struct property student.name using printf I don't need to use .c_str() and need it in order to print the situation value, if them both was declared as string, one inside struct and other as variable.

Comment: The `scanf` function is a `C`-based function.  It has no idea what a C++ `std::string` is, thus your program exhibits undefined behavior.  Why are you not using `std::cin`?  What introductory C++ book or learning material is showing usage of `scanf` over C++ input routines?  You make a similar error using `printf`.  Why not use `std::cout`?

Comment: If using `printf()` you don't need to use `std::string:::c_str()`, that's happenstance.   Without it the behaviour of the `printf()` statement is undefined - one problem with undefined behaviour is that, sometimes, the result seems perfectly valid even if it really isn't.    Your problem has nothing to do with difference between a member of a `struct` and named variables.   It has everything to do with the fact that undefined behaviour means that anything can happen - including working differently in two cases that (intuitively) should work the same.

Comment: Thank you, @Peter that was a perfect explanation.